# c# LinqtoTwitter getting ScreenName/UserID from connection context

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-twitter

I've read nearly every post with a code example in the LinqToTwitter [documentation](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Making%20API%20Calls&referringTitle=Documentation). 
I want to get the UserID or the User's ScreenName to make a call like this for the user who is logged in.

```
var friendList =
            await
            (from friend in twitterCtx.Friendship
             where friend.Type == FriendshipType.FriendIDs &&
                   friend.ScreenName == "JoeMayo"
             select friend)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

But all I can find are queries like above who have a hardcoded string for ScreenName.

Where can I get my own ScreenName/UserID out of the twitterCtx?

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first authorize, the `ScreenName` and `UserID` of the `IAuthorizer` will be populated:

```
         var credentials = auth.CredentialStore; 
         string oauthToken = credentials.OAuthToken; 
         string oauthTokenSecret = credentials.OAuthTokenSecret; 
         string screenName = credentials.ScreenName; 
         ulong userID = credentials.UserID;
```

If you're pre-loading all 4 credentials, LINQ to Twitter short-circuits to save time, bandwidth, and user annoyance by not going through the authorization process again. The side-effect is that you don't get the `ScreenName` and `UserID`, because those are a product of authorization. So, if you save someone's keys after initial authorization, so you can use them again on subsequent queries, then grab `ScreenName` and `UserID` at that time too.

Of course you have another way to obtain `ScreenName` and `UserID`. You can do a `VerifyCredentials` query, like this:

```
        try
        {
            var verifyResponse =
                await
                    (from acct in twitterCtx.Account
                     where acct.Type == AccountType.VerifyCredentials
                     select acct)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            if (verifyResponse != null && verifyResponse.User != null)
            {
                User user = verifyResponse.User;

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Credentials are good for {0}.",
                    user.ScreenNameResponse); 
            }
        }
        catch (TwitterQueryException tqe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tqe.Message);
        }
```

The `ScreenName` and `UserID` are in the `User` entity of the `User` property on the `Account` entity returned from the `VerifyCredentials` query. They are named *`ScreenNameResponse`* and *`**UserIDResponse**`* properties, respectively.